# Prove $\lim_{x \to a} \Re f(x) = \Re A$ and $\lim_{x \to a} \Im f(x) = \Im A$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I'm reading Ahlfors' complex analysis. In the book, he states that

> From $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =  A$ we obtain that \begin{align*}\lim_{x \to a} \Re f(x) = \Re A\\
> \lim_{x \to a} \Im f(x) = \Im A\end{align*}

where $x$ and $f(x)$ can be real or complex. Here also assuming that $f(x)$ is defined over some open set.

---

I wanted to quickly verify this explicitly using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit.

Since we know that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) =  A$ then we know that $\forall \varepsilon >0,  \exists \delta_{(\varepsilon)}>0$ such that if $0 < \lvert x-a \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x)-A \rvert < \varepsilon$. Noting that
$$
\lvert f(x)-A \rvert  = \bigr\lvert \overline{f(x)-A } \bigl\rvert = \bigr\lvert \overline{f(x)}-\overline{A } \bigl\lvert
$$
we see that
$$
\bigr\lvert \Re f(x)+ \Re A  \bigr\rvert = \Biggr\lvert \frac{f(x) + \overline{f(x)}}{2} + \frac{A + \overline{A}}{2} \Biggl\rvert \le \frac{\bigr\lvert f(x)- A  \bigr\rvert}{2} + \frac{\bigr\lvert \overline{f(x)}- \overline{A}  \bigr\rvert}{2} = \lvert f(x)-A \rvert< \varepsilon
$$
using the same $\varepsilon$ that we used in $f(x) \to A$. And since we know that for that $\varepsilon$ we can always find a $\delta$ such that... Then this also works for $\lim_{x \to a} \Re f(x) = \Re A$. And for the imaginary part we would to an analogous proceadure with $\Im z = \frac{z -\overline{z}}{2i}$.

Is this proof of what the author meant correct? Or am I glossing over some important parts? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's right but after "we see that", after the first $=$, you have a $+$ which should be $-$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sign errors, it should be
$$
\bigr\lvert \Re f(x) \color{red}{-} \Re A  \bigr\rvert = \Biggr\lvert \frac{f(x) + \overline{f(x)}}{2} \color{red}{-} \frac{A + \overline{A}}{2} \Biggl\rvert \le \frac{\bigr\lvert f(x)- A  \bigr\rvert}{2} + \frac{\bigr\lvert \overline{f(x)}- \overline{A}  \bigr\rvert}{2} = \lvert f(x)-A \rvert< \varepsilon
$$
to make it correct.

Alternatively you can use
$$
\Re(w)^2 + \Im(w)^2 = |w|^2 \implies |\Re(w)| \le |w|, |\Im(w)| \le |w|
$$
for $w = f(z) - A$, compare [How to prove that $-|z| \le \Re (z) \le |z|$ and $-|z| \le \Im (z) \le |z|$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3764715/how-to-prove-that-z-le-re-z-le-z-and-z-le-im-z-le-z).
$$
$$